# Difference between linking a library with -ldl and -l

Tags: compilation

I'm trying to link some VTK libraries in my program...and It is not working like this
-ldl /usr/lib/libvtkIO.so, which is the way CMake does. But If I compile it manually using -L -lvtkIO, it works. What is the difference ?

Is dynamic versus static linking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CMake tries to use the full path to the library, rather than letting the linker search the library path(s). If you use ldd on the resulting binaries you will see they are linked to the same thing (dynamically in both cases). For things like VTK it is generally best to use CMake as it also tracks things like interface libraries for you.

I think you have misunderstood some of the arguments to the linker, -lvtkIO would link to a library in the library path called libvtkIO.so, -ldl would link to a library called libdl.so. The -L argument is used to add additional paths the linker should search for libraries.